# t-sql for each loop in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, foreach

I have a table with fields. Each field belongs to one group and each field has a Field_order.
Example:

```
groupname  | fieldname | fieldorder
-----------------------------------
group 1    | field1    | 1
group 1    | field2    | 2
group 1    | field3    | 3
group 2    | field4    | 1
group 3    | field5    | 1
group 3    | field6    | 2
```

If i set `field3` of `group 1` to `fieldorder = 2` then `field2` needs to automatically be set to `fieldorder = 3`.

Same goes for if i move `field1` to `fieldorder 3`, `field3` wil be `fieldorder = 2` and `field2` needs to be `fieldorder = 1`.

I was thinking to do this with a foreach loop, but i can't seem to find one.

Comment: Whenever doing something in a **relational** database system try to avoid thinking in row-based/iteration-based terms, the problem you are describing is also solvable using set-based operations.

Comment: But how, because the fieldorder isn't a default value, it is generated out of the other field orders

Comment: First I think you need to explain the explicit rules of how your updates should work: You always want to update other entries that share the group of the entry that was just updated, but the how I don't understand yet. I assume `fieldorder` is unique amongst all fields in the same group? But how is the target fieldorder value determined? The two examples you provide don't cover all cases, can you explain the rule behind that more generally?

Comment: fieldorder is unique in every group and fieldname is the primary key. So whenever i change the order of 1 field, all other fields need to automatically change their order based on the changed field´s order. so every group wil always have order 1,2,3 etc.. for example± you can change the field with order 23 to order 2. and all fields will change to 1,2,3,4,..,50. so there will be no duplicate fieldorders

Comment: `change their order based on the changed field´s order` that's what I don't understand; after your examples the order seems arbitrary. First example after the update you will have `field1 order 1; field2 order 3; field3 order 2` and in second example `field1 order 3; field2 order 1; field3 order 2;`, do you just want to ensure `fieldorder` is unique for each group field constellation, or does the order actually matter?

Comment: maybe this picture will help me:http://puu.sh/d6axT/5e5757799f.png i can change the order of the field in the group 'Ignore'. so the order of all the fields need to be saved when I move a field. I need the specific order of all the fields when i retrieve the page again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change fieldorder to a decimal (9,1)

if you want it to go last
set fieldorder = 4 where fieldname = 'field2'

if you want it to go first
set fieldorder = 0 where fieldname = 'field2'

if you want it second
set fieldorder = 1.5 where fieldname = 'field3'

```
update table 
   set table.fieldorder = updateorder.newOrder
  from table
  join (select fieldname, row_number() over (order by fieldorder) as newOrder
          from table 
         where groupname = 'group 1') as updateorder
    on updateOrder.fieldname = table.fieldname 
   and table.fieldorder <> updateorder.newOrder
   and table.groupname = 'group 1'
```

In a comment OP posted cannot change the field type
You could do it with integer

update table set fieldorder = fieldorder*2
then the answer as posted above but you use the odd integer rather than the .5
and you would want to wrap it all in a transaction
i know not pretty but the problem is not pretty

Comment: I am using  a repository on wich i am not auhtorized to change datatypes

Comment: You could have put that detail in the question

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this slightly differently, mostly due to my dislike of triggers, and use stored procedures. I am assuming that (`GroupName`, `FieldName`) are unique in your table and are the primary key, otherwise the following will need to be adatped slightly.

So your first procedure is to create new records:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertT
    @GroupName  VARCHAR(50),
    @FieldName  VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.T (GroupName, FieldName, FieldOrder)
    SELECT  @GroupName, 
            @Field,
            ISNULL(MAX(FieldOrder), 0)  + 1
    FROM    dbo.T
    WHERE   GroupName = @GroupName;

END
```

Then a procedure to update the FieldOrder:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ChangeFieldOrder
    @GroupName  VARCHAR(50),
    @FieldName  VARCHAR(50),
    @FieldOrder INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  T
    SET     FieldOrder = CASE WHEN t.FieldName = @FieldName THEN @FieldOrder
                            ELSE t.FieldOrder + c.Motion
                        END
    FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                        Motion = SIGN(FieldOrder - @FieldOrder),
                        LowerVal = CASE WHEN @FieldOrder > FieldOrder THEN FieldOrder ELSE @FieldOrder END,
                        UpperVal = CASE WHEN @FieldOrder > FieldOrder THEN @FieldOrder ELSE FieldOrder END
                FROM    dbo.T 
                WHERE   GroupName = @GroupName
                AND     FieldName = @FieldName
            ) AS c
            INNER JOIN dbo.T AS T
                ON T.GroupName = c.GroupName
    WHERE   Motion != 0 
    AND     t.FieldOrder BETWEEN c.LowerVal AND c.UpperVal;
END
```

Then you can run each of these as follows:

```
EXECUTE dbo.InsertT 'Group 1', 'Field1';
EXECUTE dbo.InsertT 'Group 1', 'Field2';
EXECUTE dbo.InsertT 'Group 1', 'Field3';
EXECUTE dbo.ChangeFieldOrder 'Group 1', 'Field3', 2;
```

The premise of the update is simply that the only rows affected will be those between the old and new field order. The subquery `c` has the following expressions that essentially dictate the update:

```
Motion = SIGN(FieldOrder - @FieldOrder),
LowerVal = CASE WHEN @FieldOrder > FieldOrder THEN FieldOrder ELSE @FieldOrder END,
UpperVal = CASE WHEN @FieldOrder > FieldOrder THEN @FieldOrder ELSE FieldOrder END
```

`LowerVal` and `UpperVal` simply work out the upper and lower limits of the update, so that the following can be used in the `WHERE` clause:

```
t.FieldOrder BETWEEN c.LowerVal AND c.UpperVal;
```

Motion, just works out which way the other values need to move, i.e. if you decrease the order of a value, then every thing between it's old value and it's new value needs to increase by 1 to make space in the sequence, if you increase the order of a record then you need to shift everything above it, up to the new value down by one to make space for it.

Another reason to use stored procedures to manage this is that it forces the updates to be done indivually, keeping the rules simple, i.e. how would you manage a trigger if somebody just ran:

```
UPDATE  dbo.T
SET     fieldOrder = 1;
```

What would the new ordering be? This approach also allows the use of a unique constraint if required to ensure FieldOrder is unique within each group:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_T__GroupName_FieldOrder UNIQUE (GroupName, FieldOrder);
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, it sais 0 rows affected. the primary key in my database are fieldname and pagename (there are multiple groups in a page with a unique name). so i have a unique pagename wich contains multiple unique groups wich contain unique fields. but the primary key is on pagename and fieldname.

Comment: Please can you update your question with a create table statement so that I can make sure that I am working with the same structure as you are. The queries I posted worked fine in my tests, so I can only assume something has gone wrong while adapting my queries to fit your table? Thanks